# Why passwords shouldn't be used as session key

Tags: encryption, passwords, cryptography, sessionid

For the secure communication between Alice and Bob if they have pre-shared password. Why that password shouldn't be used as session key for the communication ?

Comment: Voted to close as "off topic". This doesn't appear to be a programming specific question.

Comment: Indeed, this would be better suited for our sister site, http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in this communication session you'll probably transmit significant amount of data. This data could be used to discover the password.

If you use session key, it's only valid for the period of one session, so even if it gets compromised, password stays secure. Additionally, discovering this session key will be less likely because it will change periodically, so the amount of data available to the attacker will be limited.

Comment: "*This data could be used to discover the password*" - how is session data related to password?

Comment: If the same password is used to encrypt data, attacker could possibly gather a lot of cipher data and use some kind of linear analysis to discover that password. So the point is not to have relation between session data and password.

Comment: @icepack The risk of key exposure rises as the volume of data encrypted by that key rises. I suppose the suggestion here is that cryptanalysis is easier with a greater volume of example data.

Comment: The other *major* reason is that user-chosen keys have poor entropy. At the very least, a derived key should be used rather than the raw bytes of the password.

Comment: @DuncanJones Thanks. Not sure this is a valid assumption (regarding the amount of encrypted data), but I see the reasoning

Comment: @icepack I think with most modern cryptographic algorithms, it's fairly irrelevant. However, it's still the advise given by major figures in the industry, e.g. NIST.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that an attacker discovers the data sent from the user to the server. If you are using the password as a session key, then the attacker has full access to your account.

If you use a random key, the attacker will only have access to your account during the time that session key is valid (some minutes, hours or so).

It is possible that the password is also used in another websites (your mail for example), so the attacker can gain access to even more accounts.

This example is however not realistic, because session keys are usually associated with user's IP and other relevant information. That means that the attacker would have to fake it's own IP also to use your session key.

This is also why there are some sites that don't let you change your password without entering the old one. That's because if an attacker hijacks your session, he won't be able to hijack your account. Every important change in your account (email, password, etc) should be protected with a "enter your password" field so that session hijacking doesn't become a critical security problem (it is a security problem, but just temporal and not critical).

Answer (score 0):

Passwords are typically too short, they are far from being random so their entropy may be attacked, and they stay the same, so acquired knowledge may be used in a future session. What you end up with is a kind of Vigenère-cipher known to be breakable since 1850. You have to decide yourself, whether this is "good enough".